# Infinite instantiate loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game object and it is suppose to create once object and everytime the button e is pressed, the it destroys the game object and spawns in another location. but for this case it keeps on spawning it self creating clones.

any help is appreciated!!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Medicine : MonoBehaviour
{
    public struct Transform
    {
        public float x;
        public float y;
    }
    public Vector2[] respawnLocations;
    public GameObject Medicineprefab;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("start is called");
        respawnLocations = new Vector2[3];

        respawnLocations[0] = new Vector2 { x = 8.04f, y = 5.13f };
        respawnLocations[1] = new Vector2 { x = -1.5f, y = 9.65f };
        respawnLocations[2] = new Vector2 { x = -9.93f, y = 4.7f };
        spawnMedicine();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            RespawnMedicine();
        }
    }

    void RespawnMedicine()
    {
        if (Medicineprefab != null)
        {
            Destroy(Medicineprefab);
        }
        spawnMedicine();
    }

    void spawnMedicine()
    { 
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, respawnLocations.Length);
        Vector2 spawnPosition = respawnLocations[randomIndex];
        Debug.Log(spawnPosition);
        Instantiate(Medicineprefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))` is fired _for every frame_ the player has the `E` key pressed - it doesn't fire _just once_. (I'm not familiar with Unity, so I don't know if it handles `GameObject` fields, but from here you don't seem to ever assign to the `Medicineprefab` field.

Comment: what do you mean by not assigning MedicinePrefab? i am abit confused sorry

Comment: Your code here `if (Medicineprefab != null)` will not branch when `Medicineprefab == null` - but from what I can tell, it's always going to be `null`, so `Destroy` will never get called.

Comment: i removed if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) and respawnMedicine() and it still keeps on spawning the GameObject infinitely infinitely i suspect it might be this line of code.  Instantiate(Medicineprefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that line and use your debugger to find out why it's being called then.

Comment: @Dai In Unity the prefab will be set from the inspector. The problem is Woopy tries to destroy the prefab rather than the instantiated objects.

Comment: You should check and destroy the returned object from `Instantiate`.

Comment: ahhhh i see i see thanks alot ill try work on that

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html says "Returns true during the frame the user starts pressing down the key identified by name.  It will not return true until the user has released the key and pressed it again." The way it is used in the question is correct.

Comment: `Start` calls `spawnMedicine();` which spawns a new object, presumably with this script on it and that `Start` calls `spawnMedicine();`, etc. forever.

Comment: Assuming you set a prefab in the inspector, why would you destroy it, and then try and make a new one from the thing you just destroyed.

Answer (score -1):

There might be a problem with your instanciated prefab,Is there any script attached to your prefab?
as far as i see there is no problem with your code except

```
if (Medicineprefab != null)
{
    Destroy(Medicineprefab);
}
```

you didnt give any value to "MedicinePrfab" Therefore it is always Null
If you want to Destroy the last instanciated object you can do this:

```
 void spawnMedicine()
    {
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, 
         respawnLocations.Length);
        Vector2 spawnPosition = respawnLocations[randomIndex];
        Debug.Log(spawnPosition);
        MedicinePrefab =  Instantiate(Medicineprefab, 
        spawnPosition, 
        Quaternion.identity);
    }
```

Comment: I can see 2 problems in this answer: 1. `MedicinePrfab` isn't null, as I mentioned above, it should be set elsewhere, the OP also said "it keeps on spawning itself". 2. Your code overwrites and destroys `MedicinePrefab`, so the next call to `spawnMedicine` will result in an exception.

Comment: I just run the code and got no exception , but i understande what you mean ,we can define another variable to store our instance .
i just run Woopy's code and it works fine without looping so ,i guess the only thing that might be different is the prefab , mabye something attached to prefab that causes looping